# Restore activity with right fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, restore

I have a main activity that holds fragments.
If I press home button and then re-enter my app, I want to restore the fragments backstack as I had never left.
Is this possible? I may i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand pretty well your question but if you want to come back to the previous fragment, you have to use addToBackStack(null).

Imagine that you are in one fragment: FragmentA and you call to the Fragment B

```
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragments_container, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);

        ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
```

If you don't add the line ft.addToBackStack(null), when the user press the back button from Fragment B, you never are going to come back to Fragment A. But if you use this line, mean that you are going to include the Fragment A in the queue of fragments before to pass to Fragment B. In that way, when the back button is pressed, you will come back to Fragment A.

Was that your question?

Comment: That's not it. My question is: if i leave my app (for example, pressing home button). When i re-enter my app, i want to show the fragment that was visible when i left the last time.

Comment: When you press the home button ,for example, you application is not closed, it is still running in background, so you don't have to do nothing, when you come back to the app, it is going to remember which fragment was loaded before.  Other subject is when the app is closed completly for the user or because the android system need more resources and take the decision to close your app (it was in background).

Comment: In that case, i am not pretty sure if there is a native way to keep the queue of fragments, but you could do it, saving the queue of fragments using shared preferences when the app call to the onClose method of your activity. when the app is opened again, you could restore the queue of fragments of your last session. Anyway, I think you don't really need to this task...normally, when one app is closed, should be opened for the main screen.